# 2D color and quiver plot in python with large datasets

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

In the very near future I will be doing some analysis of measurement data. This data is geographical data (e.g. height measurements and wind measurements) which has a high resolution (some 50 million x, y, and z points for example). Plotting such a dataset is very slow in matplotlib and I wonder if there are better options.

The plots I see myself creating in the near future would be a quiver plot (for the winddirections) and color plots for terrain heights. It must be noted that the x, y and z values do not line up to be a square or rectangular grid.

Besides creating figures it is likely that the dataset will also need to be shown on google maps. Would this be possible as an overlay (also with such a large dataset or would I need to overlay an image?)

Comment: I did something similar, but with a galaxy. I ended up taking a subset (e.g., take every 1000th star) and plot that in a quiverplot. It still shows the density a bit, something that was also useful for me.

Comment: Plotting a subset is something I used when this was an option, but in this particular case I'd rather plot the entire dataset since height changes might be on a small scale.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using PyQt and its [Graphics Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html).

You would define classes for each type of item, inheriting from `QGraphicsItem`, then you just add these items to a `QGraphicsScene`, and leave the rendering itself to `QGraphicsView`. This is expected to be very performant.

As for Google Maps, you can export a subset of your data to KML, and render it using a KmlLayer, or you can use an ImageOverlay as you said, or else you can try the [DataLayer API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer).

(As an alternative, you can embed a QWebKit widget pointing to GoogleMaps and overlay a QGraphicsView over it, but I think that would be a bit overkill).